# Node and mining in ARM device

Tags: cpu-mining, gpu-mining, mining-software

I have an "almost always idle" ARM home server (not a rPi, more powerful) and I was thinking running a monero node in it, plus maybe have it mine if possible/profitable.

For the node part, is the monero code compatible with ARM devices? Has anyone actually tried running a monero node in an ARM device?

For the mining part, I am thinking it might even be profitable because the device tops at 5W consumption plus it has working OpenGL and OpenCL drivers for its Mali GPU. Again, if I wanted to test the mining software, would it compile in an ARM device? has anyone actually tried it? What difficulties can I expect to get the integrated GPU to mine?

Comment: What is the CPU model you're using? You might try to compile an older version of Wolf's AMD miner, which uses OpenCL. (Newer versions use some AMD-specific OpenCL extensions, which won't work on that Mali GPU.)

Answer (score 10):

> For the node part, is the monero code compatible with ARM devices?

Yes, there are even binaries for ARMv7, which can be found [here](https://getmonero.org/downloads/). Alternatively, you could compile from [master](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero#compiling-monero). From the [pull requests](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ARM) to master, it is clear that the Monero developers are maintaining ARM support.

> Has anyone actually tried running a monero node in an ARM device?

Yes, a variety of people have ran Monero on a Raspberry Pi. For example, see [here](https://forum.getmonero.org/20/general-discussion/267/a-step-by-step-guide-to-running-a-full-node-on-raspberry-pi-2) and [here](https://forum.getmonero.org/5/support/2465/raspberry-pi2-0-9-1-0-hydrogen-helix).

> Again, if I wanted to test the mining software, would it compile in an ARM device?

Bitmonerod (the daemon) has a solominer embedded. Thus, you can simply start solo mining if you are running a full node by entering the following command in bitmonerod:

`start_mining <address> [<number_of_threads>]`

Note that the optimal amount of threads is amount of cache available divided by 2. Thus, if you have 4 MB available, you should use 2 as number of threads.

> has anyone actually tried it?

Not entirely sure about that, but there have been some question on reddit about it. See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4bj5d8/monero_mining_from_an_raspberry_pi_3/) for example.

> What difficulties can I expect to get the integrated GPU to mine?

[According to hyc](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4bj5d8/monero_mining_from_an_raspberry_pi_3/d19lsnf) mining on a 32bit OS is quite slow and inefficient. In addition, there are currently no optimizations for ARM64 yet.

Comment: Mining on an ARMv6 (raspberry pi 1B) yielded 1.25 seconds *per hash*. I don't recall my hash speeds on ARMv7. It should get significantly better on ARMv8 once we have optimized code to use the ARMv8 AES instructions.

Comment: Also, I've found that these integrated GPUs have pretty tiny local RAM, a few tens of KB. CryptoNight requires at least 2MB per thread, so I'm not very optimistic about performance on the GPUs. Still a work in progress though.

Answer (score 10):

I've been running a full node on a Geekbox for the past 6 months. This uses an RK3368 SOC with 8 Cortex-A53 cores and 2GB RAM. It's running Debian Jessie for ARM64. This little box is powerful enough to compile the entire bitmonero source tree natively (but it's still faster to cross-compile from a full-blown PC).

With the performance enhancements due to show up in the next release (0.10), it's a perfectly capable full node.

As a miner it only gets 3 hashes/second for 1 CPU core. At 4 threads it gets 12 hashes/second, and at 6 threads it gets 14 hashes/second, so peak efficiency is at 4 threads. It's not clear how much faster we can expect this to get after optimizations are written.

Comment: With optimized AES code, this box gets 6H/s for 1 thread, and up to 23H/s with 8 threads. Full test results listed here https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/52c8pg/v010_beta_for_armv8a_arm64/

Answer (score 2):

### Custom ARM fork of `cpuminer-multi`.

Take a look at [this answer](https://github.com/lucasjones/cpuminer-multi/issues/45#issuecomment-362433774) that gets `minergate-multi` working on ARM, thanks to [some genius](https://github.com/tkinjo1985) forking it and fixing it.

The basic steps are as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/tkinjo1985/cpuminer-multi.git

cd cpuminer-multi

./build.sh
```

If you're on Ubuntu/Debian, of course make sure you install the necessary packages **BEFORE**:

```
apt-get install automake autoconf pkg-config libcurl4-openssl-dev libjansson-dev libssl-dev libgmp-dev make g++
```

And then `./cpuminer --help`

I tried this on a 64-core ARM server and it worked great. Here's a screenshot of the multi-core goodness in action:

[image: 64-core mining on ARM]